# Why does my custom AdapterView not measure itself in OnMeasure

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin

I have a 2 dimensional ListView, much like a list of carousels in iOS.

However when OnMeasure() is called on each HorizontalListView I don't understand the proper way to SetMeasuredDimensions(). At the moment I am checking for a child and matching the childs MeasuredHeight.

I don't actually even need to do anything special so I would rather not override the OnMeasure() and just leave the layoutparams as wrap_content.

I don't know if this is correct as in another project OnMeasure gets called before OnLayout therefore I haven't actually Added or Measured any children yet (which I do in OnLayout() ). I also don't know how to force another Measure pass in hope that a layout pass has been.

Question is. How do I use the HoriztonalListView LayoutParams of wrap_content properly?

I have supplied the project [Here](https://bitbucket.org/freddie12/listmanipulation)

Comment: Why do you need the measurement? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: If I don't override the OnMeasure no views are displayed. I'm assuming each row will have height of zero.

If I override and give a height the list of rows are displayed.

I'm trying to achieve a list of horizontally scrolling listviews. I have achieved it through explicitly getting the first child and matching the height. I don't think this is correct though.